# Inhabilitar elementos de un Select2

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

Tengo un elemento `Select2` el cual tiene cargada 4 opciones, mediante un array.

```
<select class="select2_single form-control select-input" id="cmb" name="cmb">
   <option></option>
   @foreach($informacion as $i)
      <option value="{!! $i['id'] !!}">{!! $i['descripcion'] !!]</option>
   @endforeach
</select>
```

El tema es que lo armo con un foreach, pero cuando trae cierto Id quisiera que aparezca el `option` pero que no permita seleccionarlo (`disabled='disabled'`)

La pregunta en sí es ¿Cómo puedo poner `disabled` un elemento `option` que lo armo mediante un `foreach` usando la libreria `Select2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agregar un condicional dentro del foreach. Ej:

```
<select class="select2_single form-control select-input" id="cmb" name="cmb">
   <option></option>
   @foreach($informacion as $i)
      @if($i['id'] = ...)
      <option value="{!! $i['id'] !!}" disabled>{!! $i['descripcion'] !!]</option>
      @else
      <option value="{!! $i['id'] !!}">{!! $i['descripcion'] !!]</option>
      @endif
   @endforeach
</select>
```